# Storing bitmap from the image view

Tags: android, bitmap

I have images in the imageview which change through swipe gesture. I want to store any image from that imageview and store it or save it in my app in some-other activity and show it. I believe it can be done by

```
Bitmap bm=((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

But i am unable to implement it fully. Please if somebody could help.

Comment: Why can't you implement it? What is the error? You need to be more specific if you want us to have any chance in helping you...

Comment: @Mikel I mean whats the next step should i take?

Comment: Again you need to be more specific, where do you want to store it? Memory or storage? And you should google it or search SO before asking your question, there are several answers about this topic, for instance [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662258/how-to-save-a-bitmap-on-internal-storage) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674634/saving-images-to-internal-memory-in-android) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649154/save-bitmap-to-location) ...

Comment: Check the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) on how to use and display Bitmaps correctly.

Comment: @Mikel Sorry for being not very precise, but i did mention in my question that i am trying to save the image in another activity within the app with the click of the button

Comment: well then check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2459624/562840) answer and see if it fits your needs.