# Can I make an activity to Bitmap?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, bitmap

I want to make Bitmap data from activity's output. Activity contains a fragment, and I can't modify it.

I don't want to activity to real screen and just want to make bitmap data. How can I do it.

Comment: question not able to understand

Comment: Question it self not clear what you want,just elaborate your question.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you specify your question? What have you tried? What have you now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want something like a screenshot of your activity.

In order to get the root view of your activity (what you're currently seeing), do this:

```
View view = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
view.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

and then you'll have a Bitmap of your activity, referenced by the `bitmap` variable.

Do what you want with that Bitmap, like [saving it to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15662384/2823516).

Answer (score 1):

If you wan to capture the Activity's View hierarchy to a Bitmap, try this:

```
View view = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```