# how to download image from server and store in internal storage using JSON in android

Tags: android, json, bitmap

I want to download images from server using json and storing it in internal storage , after that show image one by one. I have the JSON format can any body help me with how to do it???
My json is:

```
    {
"_id" : ObjectId("55b09029e56e5ecc1577f00e"),
"user" : ObjectId("559a298d9969172f3ffeaa6d"),

"name" : "ddd", 
"language" : "english",


"pages" :

[ {

"_id" : ObjectId("55b0902be56e5ecc1577f00f"),


"page_image" : [

{ "image" : "images.png", "_id" : ObjectId("55b09032e56e5ecc1577f010") }, 
{ "image" : "20140624_172041_fbhciha_sm.jpeg", "_id" : ObjectId("55b0903ce56e5ecc1577f011") }, 
{ "image" : "673.jpg", "_id" : ObjectId("55b09042e56e5ecc1577f012") } ] } ], "__v" : 4 }
```

Comment: I would suggest to learn json parsing first: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/
Once you will under stand it and able to fetch image url from your response then use @streamride approach to show your image to any view.

Comment: sure, it would be good

Comment: :- Once you will finish above I would suggest to use Picasso( http://square.github.io/picasso/) for Image downloading

All work starting from download image from url to bitmap conversion and set to image view will be handle by Picasso. For example : Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(view/*Your image view*/);

Comment: fine but i need to store the downloaded image first into device then i need to show it to the View???

Comment: Follow this this tutorial (http://androidappmasters.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=15) once you will start using Picasso, In the last section you will find the way to store your downloaded image to you device.

Comment: I am done with getting the url from the json now i need to download images from these url and need to store them in internal storage ?? help please how can i do that ?? @AdarshYadav

Comment: :- Sorry for late response please refer my answer below. Hope it will help you. Cheers !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Add `compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'`inside build.gradle or download jar file from [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

2- `Picasso.with(this)
.load("Your image url here")
.into(target);`
If you list then you can also use above during traversing your list(inside any  loop).

3-As target in above class displaying compile time error. Put following code as your inner class.

```
private Target target = new Target() {
@Override
 public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
       @Override
     public void run() {

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/image1.jpg");
        try {
           file.createNewFile();
           FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
           bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, ostream);
           ostream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }}
  }).start(); }
   @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {}
   @Override
   public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
  if (placeHolderDrawable != null) {} }};
```

4-If you are still facing problem in understanding above code please refer following example. [Picasso - Image downloading and caching library for Android](http://androidappmasters.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=15)

5- ` for(int i = 0; i < cons.length(); i++)

```
{
    JSONObject c = cons.getJSONObject(i);
    imgURL = c.getString(image);
    Picasso.with(this)
            .load(imgURL)
            .into(new Target() {
                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/image1.jpg");
                            try {
                                file.createNewFile();
                                FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, ostream);
                                ostream.close();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }}
                    }).start();
                }

                @Override
                public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                }
            });
}`
```

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < cons.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = cons.getJSONObject(i);

                        imgURL = c.getString(image);
                        Log.i("Url: ", " " + imgURL);

                        imgURLx[i] = imgURL;
                        Log.i("Url in array"," "+ imgURLx[i]);

Comment: i can access the image urls and i am storing them to an array of strings, now i need to store these images to internal storage, i have posted my code in a comment above.

Comment: for the above code you provided, there is only one link of image that can be stored...i need to store all images in an order ?? @Adrash Yadav

Comment: @HassanHameed :- Check out point 5 in above answer and replace your for loop with above code.

Comment: app is now starting to crash at Picasso.with(MainActivity.this) , i have copiles the lib of picasso...

Comment: but if i use Glide it works fine... does the Glide do the storing process?

Comment: Check your imports carefully it should be same as :
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.squareup.picasso.Target;

Comment: I have never used Glide but as per the implementation it's looks similar to Picasso.

Comment: Can you post your crash log?

Comment: I have sorted it out, the code of picasso should be placed in onPostExecute not in the do InBackground @Adarsh Yadav

Comment: @HassanHameed:- Cool finally we did it. I have now you understand quite well about json parsing and image loading .
Good Luck !!!

Comment: i want to ask one more thing that i want to store image in a folder, and only one image is storing i want to store all of them ??

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest way is to use Glide library (https://github.com/bumptech/glide)
you can get bitmap as

```
Bitmap bitmap = Glide.with(pContext).load(url).asBitmap().into(100, 100).get();
```

and then save bitmap

be sure that you call that method in new thread

Comment: but i need to parse this json first ? isn't it ?? i need to ask that how to parse it?

Comment: @HassanHameed ok, you can do like this -   JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(<your_posted_code>);   then, JSONArray pageImages = obj.getJSONArray("page_images");   and for( int i=0; i < pageImages.length(); i++) {  JSONObject image = pageImages.get(i); String url = image.getString("image"); }

Comment: @HassanHameed sorry, I missed JSONArray named pages, you need to parse like I posted above

Comment: this is a nested array first i have array of pages then inside it there is array of page images.. <your_posted_code> i want to make it dynamic in response to the  server request it will give me json, how to impement that json ??

Comment: @HassanHameed I posted as answer how to parse it

Comment: i have a download button, i want when i click it and it sends request to server and in response a json will be generated in format that i have posted above ?? how to send request o server ? on button click

Answer (score 0):

You get String in response to server.
Then you create json object

```
String strResponse = ...
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(strResponse);
JSONArray pagesArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("pages");
for (int i=0;i<pagesArray.length();i++){
  JSONObject pageObj = pagesArray.getJSONObject(i);
  JSONArray pageImagesArray = pageObj.getJSONArray("page_image");
  for (int j=0;j<pageImagesArray.length();j++) {
     JSONObject image = pageImagesArray.getJSONObject(j);
      String urlImg = image.getString("image");
  }
}
```

Comment: in response of the server i am not getting string i am getting the json in the format i have posted in my question ???

Comment: sorry i could not understand .. which two lines and where to pass ?

Comment: i am having a download button on click it will send request to server and in response i will get json and then i have to parse it, i am wondering how to do this from download request to parsing this json ?? and saving images to device ???

Comment: you said you get json format, is that String object or JSONObject object?

Comment: So, if the name of your jsonObject is "jsonObject" you start from this line to parsing it   (JSONArray pagesArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("pages");)

Comment: alright this is good, i can get the string of the image, now if i want to download the images from the server and to store it in internal storage ??

Comment: then when you get Bitmap object (as I posted) you can save it like described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/15662384/1216446

Comment: i have got the url of the image from the json.. now i need to store those images into my internal disk and show them on a read button ???

Comment: I am done with getting the url from the json now i need to download images from these url and need to store them in internal storage ?? help please how can i do that ?? @streamride

Comment: @HassanHameed  first read that http://stackoverflow.com/a/31585778/1216446  and then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662258/how-to-save-a-bitmap-on-internal-storage/15662384#15662384