# Saving a URL to internal storage

Tags: java, android

So the title slightly misleading. I've put the URl in a drawable.

```
public Drawable getDrawableFromURL(String url) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
        return d;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I had it has a bitmap originally but kept getting nullpointers and `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`, which I've managed to fix, but the nullpointer comes around again. So I'm stuck on how to save to internal, because I can save it to SD fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
public class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {


 protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String urldisplay = urls[0];
    Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
    try {
        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
        mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Error", e.getStackTrace().toString());

    }
    return mIcon11;
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
   // save your bitmap here

 }
}
```

to call this `AsyncTask` use below code

```
 new DownloadImage().execute(url);
```

Comment: This doesn't bring back any errors for me. Brilliant. Do you know where the images are being saved however?

Comment: you need to save this bitmap in to your sdcard

Comment: I'm looking to not save to an SD card. Using internal storage.

Comment: @ChristopherMckenzie check this link it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662258/how-to-save-a-bitmap-on-internal-storage