# Android file is not creating

Tags: android, file

In my Android project i'm saving an image file into the device. in there I use the following code for creating file.

```
File folder = new File(getFilesDir());
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            folder.mkdir();
        }
File imageFile = new File(folder, filename);
try
  {
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
  bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
  fos.close();
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

but this gives me File not found exception when creating FileOutputStream

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
```

so the file seems not creating. how can I fix this.

Comment: did you add run time permission if you are targetting android >23

Comment: by debug, which is the value of "filename"

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley, the file is /storage/emulated/0/PAssets/PProfilePicture.png

Comment: [have a look at this, should solve your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15662384/4700782)

Comment: The file was not created because the folder 'PAssets ' was not created have a look through file manager, try creating folder manually and then execute your code and you will see your file is created.

Comment: Hi even im working on same kind of project. Are you trying to create a file inside your app Folder ?

Comment: The issue was I'm not checking run time permissions as my emulator runs Android 6. thanks @NileshRathod for your information. thanks all :) :) :)

Comment: @SamanthaWithanage most welcome happy to help you

Comment: `folder.mkdir();` Check the return value and do not continue if false. And there is nothing with 'PAssets' in your code.

Comment: change folder.mkdir();
to folder.mkdirs();  Because ur file directory could be many sub directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I'm using an Android emulator running Android 6.0 and I'm not checking runtime permissions. Prior to API 23 when accessing external storage we need runtime permissions. I checked the permissions as below.

```
public  boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return true;
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                return false;
            }
        }
        else { 
            return true;
        }
    }
```

an once permission granted it received through following callback so that we can perform our task.

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if(grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            saveTempImage(bmp, filename);
        }
    }
```

Thanks all for kind help!

Comment: Nonsense. `getFilesDir()` is internal memory and you do not need any permission for it. `the file is /storage/emulated/0/PAssets/PProfilePicture.png` Impossible as `/storage/emulated/0` is not internal memory but external. Your code does not represent your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `folder` wasn't created. If the `folder` has a path like this one: `/folder1/folder2`. Could you try to create the `folder1` first then create the `folder2` ?. After that, you run your code again.

Comment: I'm creating only one folder "PAssets". my file path when debugging is as following. */storage/emulated/0/PAssets/PProfilePicture.png*

Comment: Could you post your logs and show me the `getFilesDir()` method ?

Comment: private String getFilesDir() {
        return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + ASSETS_FOLDER_NAME;
    }

Comment: I did like you and it works fine. I don't know there is  a '/' in the `ASSETS_FOLDER_NAME` constant :final String downloadPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/PAssets";
                File folder = new File(downloadPath);
                if (!folder.exists()) {
                    boolean value = folder.mkdir();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Create dir: " + value);
                }

                File imageFile = new File(folder, "PProfilePicture.png");

Comment: If you use Android 6 or higher. Could you check `Storage` permission is enable in the app setting ? If it is not enable then enable it and try again. See this link to check that: https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/android-basics-manage-app-permissions-marshmallow-higher-0168220/

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly create a file as following :

```
 File imageFile = new File(folder, filename);

 if(!imageFile.exists()){
    imageFile.createNewFile();
 }
```