# How can I move Bitmap from one class to another while both classes are in one activity?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a class where a photo is captured and Bitmap is stored in the `ImageView`. In another class I got brush tool (canvas). If I create a new Bitmap in a second class I can draw on canvas but I can't draw on the captured image from the first class. How could I move the bitmap from first class to another?

**Method of the first class of captured image**

```
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

**Method of the second class with the brush tool and empty canvas**

```
public void init(DisplayMetrics metrics) {
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    currentColor = DEFAULT_COLOR;
    strokeWidth = BRUSH_SIZE;
}
```

Comment: You have the bit map in the first class before you send it to `setImageBitmap` just put it in an object you can reach from both places and you are done.

Comment: you can call putExtra() on the Intent when you start the activity and call getExtrax() in the second class

Comment: Get the bitmap path as static field and then you able to use anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the bitmap and get its path. Now pass that path into your activity intent. Then retrieve it from other activity using intent.getExtras()

To save bitmap you can check this answer '[How to save a bitmap on internal storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662258/how-to-save-a-bitmap-on-internal-storage)'

If its not an activity then use set get methods

```
public void setBitmap( Bitmap b ) {
bitmap= b;

}

public Bitmap getBitmap() {
return bitmap;
}'
```

Check this tutorial for set get methods 
'http://www.javawithus.com/tutorial/get-and-set-methods'

Comment: Would that work since my second class is not an activity?

Comment: No. In that case you can simply use set get methods. Check my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just take a one static variable of bitmap

Set your received bitmap into that variable and access that variable by its class name directly into your second activity.

Comment: When I create static bitmap variable  and set it to canvas in init method of the second it crashes :(

Comment: For example i put imageView.setImageBitmap(MainActivity.bitmap); this in a second class and it crashes

Comment: did you initialize that bitmap ?